# Convert extrude plane to solid

Tags: modeling

I have one problem, I would like to know how I can convert an extruded plane into a solid.

Comment: Hello and welcome, please keep only one question per post, make as many as necessary. Faces don't have "origins" the dots are selection helpers.

Comment: Ok, I've already reissued the question. Thank you very much for answering. I have clarified several things.

Answer (score 1):

You may have already solved this, but do this :

1/ Select plane and go into edit mode (tab)

2/ Select All (a)

3/ Activate Extrude mode (e)

4/ Depending on the orientation of your plane, limit extrusion to the X, Y or Z axis by selecting "X", "Y" or "Z".

You plane should now be a solid. Just note that you need to be aware of the normals for your faces you have created with this method. Normals explained [here](https://all3dp.com/2/blender-recalculate-normals-simply-explained/)